# 419 Page Expired while login or registering on laravel 7

Tags: laravel, post, server, csrf, laravel-7

I keep on getting this error after submitting my login details. This error comes out during the login and registration process. My csrf token is intact in each form. The same application works well locally but when hosted online it doesn't. What could be the problem??

permission on storage and bootstrap is 775

Comment: What is you session driver?

Comment: I am using 'file' session driver.

Comment: Another possibility is that your cookie expires immediatly. Or you gave it the wrong domain name. Check your settings in `config/session.php` and the `.env` corresponding values.